# pdf (transformations of variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

If X has the pdf $f(x)=\frac13, -1<x<2$, zero elsewhere,find the pdf of $Y=X^4$. here is my solution: The support of $Y$ is $(1,16)$. Now, $P(Y\le y)=P (X\le y^{\frac14})$.. then the cdf of Y is ${y^\frac14+1} \over {3} $  ,(1,16)

Answer (score 0):

For the interval $1< x \leq 2$ (or $1 < y \leq 16$) we can use the transformation:  $$\;f_Y(y) = f_X(g_x(y)) \left|\dfrac{\mathrm d g_x(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right|\qquad\text{where }g_x(y) = y^{1/4}$$

For the interval $-1\leq x \leq 1$, which is $0\leq y \leq 1$, we have a *slight* complication that the function $y=x^4$ is not invertable.  There are two $x$ values for every distinct $y$.

Fortunately we can use symmetry.  Since the density at each value is equal, they each contribute half effect to the probability mass.  $f_X(g_x(y)) = f_X(g_{x^+}(y))+f_X(g_{x^-}(y))$

$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 
2 \; f_X(g_{x^+}(y))\; \left|\dfrac{\mathrm d g_{x^+}(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right| &:  y\in [0, 1] \\[2ex] 
f_X(g_{x^+}(y))\; \left|\dfrac{\mathrm d g_{x^+}(y)}{\mathrm d y}\right| & : y\in (1, 16] \\[2ex]
0 & : \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}\quad\text{where }f_X(x)=\frac 1 3, \; g_{x^+}(y) = |y^{1/4}|$$